# How to capture video in Octave?

Tags: video, octave

Is there a native way to **capture video** in **Octave**?

In Matlab I'm used to use following (also maybe useful for other people):

```
a = imaqhwinfo('linuxvideo',1)  # or "imaqhwinfo('winvideo',1)" in Windows
a.SupportedFormats              # check supported formats
vid = videoinput('linuxvideo', 1, 'YUYV_640x480'); # open video stream with one of supported formats

start(vid);                     # start processing video
preview(vid);                   # open preview window

pics = cell(1,20)               # create array to store images from video
for i = 1:20                    
   pause(1);                    # every 1 second ...
   pics{i} = getsnapshot(vid);  # get video frame and save into corresponding position in array
end
```

But in Octave none of video related functions work. It is also possible to use [Octave bindings for OpenCV](http://octave-swig.sourceforge.net/octave-opencv.html) to capture video, but I'm primarily looking for more *pure* and *portable* way.

Comment: You might have to roll your own.  You can convert your video into jpg's with a non octave tool, then use `I = imread ("myfile.jpg");` http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/octave/octave_20.html

Comment: Octave's video package is unmaintained and hasn't been released in many years. The development version has been reported to work, you may want to try it.

Comment: @carandraug: thanks, it looks like the best option for the moment.

Comment: Just a quick comment regarding portability. You can check whether you're on Linux or Windows by calling `ispc()` or `isunix()` in Octave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install and load image-acquisition package.
For more information, read the Wiki: http://wiki.octave.org/Image_acquisition_package

Comment: It has been long since I used Octave last time, so I just take your answer on trust without actually testing. It will be great if someone else could verify it and drop comment here.

Answer (score 1):

If other solutions fail, you can try capturing frame by frame. You can use a for loop and add/bind the frames together. aviread is already there to capture frames. Atleast this is how I did when everything else failed.